# EF CF combine one to one with one to many relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I've done research about that, but I didn't find any solution. I'm using SQL CE 4.0 and I want to make relations like:

```
public class Process
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int CurrentStageID {get;set;}

   [ForeignKey("CurrentStageID")]
   public virtual Stage CurrentStage {get;set;}

   public virtual ICollection<Stage> Stages {get;set;}
}

public class Stage
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int ProcessId {get;set;}

   [ForeignKey("ProcessId")]
   public virtual Process Process {get;set;}
}
```

But during database initialization I get Exception:

> The referential relationship will result in a cyclical reference that is not allowed. [ Constraint name = FK_dbo.Stages_dbo.Processes_ProcessId ]

Such relation is correct?

I also  use `OnModelCreating()` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Process>()
     .HasMany(p=>p.Stages)
     .WithRequired(s=>s.Process)
     .HasForeignKey(s=>s.ProcessId);
```

Anyone can help me with that?

AD.
If I add `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` I get:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> SQLCEEngine.Proces_Etapy: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Process_Stages_Source' in relationship 'Process_Stages'. 
>       Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'